# Existence of solutions for $x'=f(t,x)$ for $f$ not necessarily $C^1$, but with other conditions

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Let $f:\mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$ be a continuous, locally Lipschitz function that satisfies the following condition:
>
> $$|f(t,x)|\leq C(1+|x|)\; , \forall (t,x)\in \mathbb{R}\times\mathbb{R}^n$$
>
> Show that the IVP $x' = f(t,x),\; x(t_0)=x_0$ admits a unique solution.

We can get existence of solutions from Peano's existence theorem. It's also easy to see that $C(1+|x|)$ is globally Lipschitz. Though, I don't know how to connect the dots. It feels like we would need $f$ to be globally Lipschitz to be able to say anything about uniqueness of solutions...

Comment: The case where $f$ doesn't depend on $t$ is proved as Proposition IV.3 in Zehnder's book *Lectures on Dynamical Systems*, using Grönwall's lemma. Probably something similar works in the general case.

Answer (score 1):

With the equation locally Lipschitz you also get that the solutions are locally unique. As any branching of IVP solutions is also a local event, local uniqueness is sufficient for global uniqueness, that is, for as long as the solution is defined.

What is usually associated with a linear bound of $f$ of the given form is that the domain of any solution is $\Bbb R$. But your task description does not even mention that?

Comment: Your question is correct, that's exactly what I'm supposed to prove. Seems like I forgot to write the most important part of the problem.